# Django How do i get the customer id automatically while customer post the booking form?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

i am newbie in django how do i get the id of customer model while submitting the form .for eg

john is submitting the form of booking i want automatically get who submit the booking .means while customer register the form and the link will sended to the customer for booking. and in booking i want to initialize the customer automatically for the booking. means john booked the car and given detail for when he want the car for booking .

**Model**

```
class Booking(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "booking"
        verbose_name = "Booking"
        verbose_name_plural = "Bookings"
        ordering = ['-booking_date']

    booking_car_car = models.ForeignKey(
        Car,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='booking_car_car_key'
    )
    booking_customer_customer = models.ForeignKey(
        Customer,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='booking_customer_customer'
    )
    booking_start_date = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_end_date = models.DateField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_total_price = models.IntegerField(
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )
    booking_approved = models.NullBooleanField(
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )
    booking_date = models.DateTimeField(
        auto_now_add=True,
        blank=False,
        null=False
    )

    def __str__(self):
        return self.booking_customer_customer.customer_firstname


class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=64,null= False)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    customer_age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(blank=True, max_length=100)
    license_year = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    tlc_number = models.IntegerField(blank=False ,null=False)
    contact_num =models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
    contact_email = models.EmailField(blank =False)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

:

can anyone help me with the code because i am not getting the customer for the booking . all customers are showing in it and i dont want that drop down i want that selected automatically.

Comment: Please post the relevant code with details about how to reproduce it.

Comment: @SachinKukreja i think its relevant . because i am using it with my cms .. please tell me  the code what to do where do i put in my forms ?

Comment: @SachinKukreja i just want the customer id automatically in it while submitting the form . for example you are user ill send a link to you with your id

Comment: No one can read this entire code and help you. You need to share what exactly is happening where and in which parts of it you are facing problems with. We can't guess the control flow of your application.

Comment: I think you've really over-complicated this.  For example you're setting `book_customer_name = request.POST.get('book_customer_name')` and then later you're doing `booking_approval.book_customer_name = book_customer_name`.  It already is so you don't need to do this.  Can I suggest you read about Modelforms and include your validation within that.  You can then assign a user within the model form using `form=BookingForm(initial={'customer': customer})` (assuming you've already got customer.

Comment: @Henrym can you tell me . i use send mail i want tgat user to send mail with booking form url . in url i want the customer id .

Comment: if user is authenticated then you have access using request.user.id

Comment: I am not using user . i am using customer . please tell me how to do with customer send a link of booking with customer id in it

Comment: @HenryM tell me the code please

Comment: goran can you make the function ?